# Centos Firewall interferes with docker network routing

Tags: docker, docker-compose, routes, centos

The default CentOS 8 firewall setup seems to prevent routing between two container within the same docker network. I found a related problem [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/199966/how-to-configure-centos-7-firewalld-to-allow-docker-containers-free-access-to-th), but the solution did not work for me.  After docker compose the nginx containers ip is 172.19.0.2

```
# docker-compose.yml

version: "3"
services:   
  nginx:
    image: "nginx"
    expose:
      - "80"
    networks:
      - "testnet"

networks:
  testnet:
    driver: "bridge"
```

Trying to reach it, with a busybox container attached to the testnet fails.

```
busybox-container$ nc -v 172.19.0.2:80
nc: 172.19.0.2:80 (172.19.0.2:80): No route to host

busybox-container$ ping -c1 172.19.0.2
...
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0% packet loss

busybox-container$ ping -c1 nginx
Ping: bad address 'nginx'
```

After stopping the firewalld and restarting the docker service `nc` seems to work, resolution does not. On an Arch-Linux system, the same compose works as expected.

I think it is the firewall making problems, so how can I configure the firewall/iptables correctly?

Comment: Any luck? I'm curious, facing a similar problem.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I worked around it with fixed IPs and never touched the compose again. If you come to a conclusion, I'll happily accept your answer!

Comment: Hey I was stuck in almost the same situation.  One of the answer in the post you referenced to actually worked for me!  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/591654/443199